# how to use restfb java api to register new game achievement?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I see that game achievements are not one of the supported object of the library. Is there a generic way to go about posting other unsupported object types?

Answer (score 1):

Generic meaning using the supported SDK or using the API directly via HTTP calls?

The PHP SDK or a direct POST to `/APP_ID/achievements` with the App Access token will do this.
If all you're doing is registering achievements, you'll only need to do this once, so just do it via the [Debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) - you can get the app access token via the [Access Token tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/)

Comment: the restfb is a java api that has native java support for various FB graph objects. But achievements are not one of the supported types. I've found that you can publish in a general way, I'll post when it's all working properly

Comment: Have to admit it took me a while to realise that registering achievements is actually just storing a reference to a preexisting url for the object hosted on the apps domain. I assume it was just an object creation method which you would use when a user achieves something in the game. If this is a one off, how do you pubish a user achievement event?

Comment: Once you register the achievement against the app (once per achievement), you make a POST with the app access token to `/USER_ID/achievements?achievement=[URL TO ACHIEVEMENT]`)

Comment: thank you! that clears things up, there's two "create" sections on the documentation page! didn't expect to have to look for another one once I'd seen the first!